# how to get an an edge which has the maximum value of a edge property from a vertex

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

Scenario: Find which is the job with most experience of an employee Vertex which has out edge `WorkedAs` and has an edge property `workedForYears` which has the experience in years for that job.

I have used

```
g.V().has('EmployeeId','1234').outE('WorkedAs').values('workedForYears').max()
```

This would return me an integer. Is there any way I can get the edge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `order().by().limit(1)` pattern rather than `max()` so you don't transform the items in the traversal into an integer.

```
g.V().has('EmployeeId','1234').outE('WorkedAs').as('e') \
     .order().by('workedForYears', decr).limit(1).select('e')
```

Notice that I used the `as()` step ([As Step docs](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#as-step)) to label a particular spot in the Gremlin traversal. Then after other processing, you can jump back to that particular spot by using `select()`.

Comment: You don't need to jump back to "e", you are actually still at "e".

Comment: oh thank you Jason but would this effect the process time considering i do it on a larger scale of over 1000 edges , as we are using limit step does it store all the 1000 results from order and give us the first one . though in this scenario it would be silly for an employee to do 1000 jobs  i have just asked so that can i use this on data with more than a 1000 edges of size